# Does NP mean verifiable in polynomial time or solvable in polynomial time?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, np

Is NP defined as *verifiable* in polynomial time, or *solvable* in polynomial time? Verifiable meaning that the solution can be checked in polynomial time, and solvable meaning that the solution can be found in polynomial time?

Answer (score 1):

NP is a class of problems whose solution is **verifiable** in polynomial time on a *deterministic* Turing machine.
Alternatively, NP is a class of problems whose solution is **solvable** in polynomial time on a *nondeterministic* Turing machine.

Please look [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9556/what-is-the-definition-of-p-np-np-complete-and-np-hard).

Comment: Are those definitions equivalent, though?

Comment: I would say these definitions are different but result in the same class of problems, NP.  You can easily prove that any problem verifiable in polynomial time on a deterministic TM is solvable on in polynomial time on a nondeterministic TM and vise versa. Advantage of the first definition (via verifiable) is that it is easy to show that given a solution it is verifiable in polynomial time, rather than come up with a nondeterministic TM solving the problem in polynomial time.

Comment: So... NP-complete problems are NP, but we don't have a polynomial-time algorithm (deterministic or non-deterministic) to solve any NP-complete problem.

Comment: NP-complete problems are NP-hard problems (every problem in NP-class is reducible to them) which belong in NP-class. Whether or not there is a polynomial time algorithm (running on a deterministic TM) that solves an NP-complete problem is a long standing mystery. You should have heard about the cliche P = NP problem. People believe these classes are not equal.